# Select statement gives different set of records

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   stu_empl_pers 
WHERE  site_id = 'DEXLER';
```

returns 22 records.

but

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   stu_empl_pers a 
WHERE  a.status = 'A' 
        OR a.faculty = 1 
        OR a.staff = 1 
           AND a.site_id = 'DEXLER';
```

returns 691 records.It considers different site_id also.Can anybody elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need status=A and site_id='dexler'as mandatory

then, could you try this?

```
Select count(*) from stu_empl_pers a 
WHERE (a.faculty=1  OR a.staff=1) 
      AND a.status='A' AND a.site_Id = 'DEXLER';
```

Comment: It result for other than 'A' status also.I need status=A and site_id='dexler'as mandatory

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE a.status='A' or a.faculty=1  OR a.staff=1 AND a.site_Id = 'DEXLER';
    (true/false    or  true/false  or (true/false  and  true/false))
```

maybe this will be more easier to see what your `WHERE` statement mean

if one of `OR`s (except the one with `AND`) become true the record will be added to the result

think `AND` like multiplication operand in math it has priority over `OR` which can be considered like `sum` operand in math

2*2-1 = 3 Not 2

Answer (score 1):

That's because the filter conditions are different. The `OR` will return all records abiding to both filter condition.

Maybe what you're looking for in the second query is;

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   stu_empl_pers a 
WHERE  ( a.status = 'A' 
          OR a.faculty = 1 
          OR a.staff = 1 ) 
       AND a.site_id = 'DEXLER';   <-- missing brackets
```

Where you're adding a second level filter `(a.status='A' OR a.faculty=1 OR a.staff=1)` to the first query.

Comment: It result for other than 'A' status also.I need status=A and site_id='dexler'as mandatory

Comment: Just remove it from the bracket, and add it after, like `(a.faculty=1 OR a.staff=1) AND a.status='A'`